# KeyError despite column header existing?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to train a linear regressor with Tensorflow.

Fitting works fine if I instantiate the learner by determining the real-valued columns automatically.

```
auto_feature_columns =
    tf.contrib.learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(
        training_examples)
linear_regressor = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(
  feature_columns=auto_feature_columns,
  optimizer=tf.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.002),
  gradient_clip_norm=3.14
)
```

However, I get KeyErrors (for all 3 columns) when I try to specify the columns manually:

```
linear_regressor = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(
  feature_columns=[
      tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column('tailLength'),
      tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column('whiskerLength'),
      tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column('playfulness')
  ],
  optimizer=tf.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.002),
  gradient_clip_norm=3.14
)
```

That is odd since I am sure that those 3 are features of my training data.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

does the KeyError happen when you try to fit the estimator?

If so, perhaps you should be using an input function, allowing feature manipulation, which returns feature_columns and labels having those keys, as in https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/input_fn/

I had the same error when using estimator.fit(x, y)...

Cheers,

Rafael.